# не работает метод count в запросе к базе

Tags: php, mysql, count

Почитал похожий пост с этой темой здесь и ничего не понял. Мне нужно просто узнать количество строк в таблице. Некоторые строки удалены, поэтому поле id уже не отражает реальной цифры. Выполняю вот такой запрос:

```
public function get_comments() {
    $query_str = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM comment";
    $params_arr = array();
    $connection = $this->connect->start();
    $query = $connection->prepare($query_str);
    $count = $query->execute($params_arr);

    var_dump($count);

    // return $count;
}
```

и на экране получаю bool(true). проблема именно в самом запросе, так как все остальные функции у меня написаны точно так же и все работает отлично. Как мне написать запрос чтобы вышла просто цифра, например 30 или 55?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Всё верно, execute возвращает bool [подробнее](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/pdostatement.execute.php)

Вам нужно сделать вывод затронутых строк с помощью метода `fetchColumn` [подробнее](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/pdostatement.fetchcolumn.php)

```
$query = $connection->prepare($query_str);
$query->execute($params_arr);
$count = $query->fetchColumn();
```

Comment: $count = $query->fetchColumn();  не result, а query->fetchColumn. А так все заработало!! спасибо!!!

Comment: @РенатоЗакиров да исправил опечатку, Если вам помог мой ответ пометьте его ответом